# Angular 2 Form Validation Pattern Required

Tags: forms, validation, angular

I´m using Angular 2 and i want to do a form Validation.
Here´s my input:

```
<td><input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max="100" step="1" pattern="^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][0][0])?" name="postEpg" [(ngModel)]="selectedTimer.PostEPG"></td>
```

My problem now is, that the validation says, this is incorrect, when i don´t fill the field...
But the field ISN´T required, so it should be ok, if theres nothing...
But if there´s something, it has to match the pattern...

Has anyone an idea how to reach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about simply modifiying the pattern like:
`pattern="^$|^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][0][0])?"`
This should allow an empty string or your pattern.

Comment: mh, i don´t know why, but with this solution the form is always vaild...
maybe it´s a problem, that the 'ngModel' variable MAY not exist on the selctedTimer...

Comment: Hey, there was a mistake in the regex, I used `?` instead of `$` (asserts position at the end of the string), I fixed it now.